# Google Sheets script for tab color based on a single cells value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

we use google sheets to dispatch orders daily from multiple locations (usually 20-50 tabs daily).  Each plant has an individual color assigned to keep the document some what orderly and easily recognized visually.

We have several "Master Tabs" based upon shipping location we will copy/duplicate that Master Tab, update the order information and finally rename to start the shipping process.

My struggle is.........

I'm looking for a script that will change the tab color when a specific cell on that individual tab (same cell on every tab) is updated. We use tab color in the central office to determine order status since the document is "live"

```
    BUT..... these orders could possibly ship again later in the week so we will copy the order forward that date and update items as needed.
```

Foreseeable problem is how to make the functionality carry forward so when that specific cell value is deleted the tab goes back to the default color until it has been "shipped".

**** We have a Master Order Sheet that we copy and rename to today's date so i would add the script there to make sure the functionality remains.

**** Any help on writing this script (with example info inserted) be greatly appreciated.  I know enough to be dangerous

Comment: Why never try `conditional formatting`?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done this way for example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 && e.range.rowStart != 1) return;

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.value == '0' || !e.value)  sheet.setTabColor(undefined);
  if (e.value == '1') sheet.setTabColor('red');
  if (e.value == '2') sheet.setTabColor('blue');
}
```

If value of the cell A1 is changed to '0' or '' tab gets default (undefined) color. If the cell will changed to '1' tab gets red color. In case of '2' tab gets blue color.

The cell must be changed manually. If it will changed by a script or via a formula the trigger `onEdit()` will not work.

Comment: so when i copy and paste the script, i get the following error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ TAB Color.gs:2"  I know it's tied to cell location and i'm wondering if you left it open for me to determine and i just dont know how? The cell i would like to use is "M1"

Comment: The function `onEdit()` is a special function -- 'trigger'. It doesn't run from the Script Editor by the button 'Run'. It fires automatically when you edit your sheet.

Comment: Paste my code in Script Editor (you already have done it, I suppose). Go to you spreadsheet and write in cell `A1` number `1`. The tab at the bottom should change its color to red. Then try to write in cell `A1` number `2`. The tab should become blue. For zero (or empty) state in cell `A1` the tab will have no color.